# Show Leaflet images in C# app

Tags: c#, download, leaflet

I have a Leaflet website that uses a custom tile set for a game map.
I want to display in my C# client app, tiles from the Leaflet map using basically the same algorithm, as if re-creating leaflet in C#.

I already have the placeholder tiles layed out in a grid and have basic navigation, but running into the problem of knowing the tile values to use for the URL (from leaflet docs):
'http://map.somedomain.com/{layer}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'

I have the layers names, and I want to know the exact X,Y for each tile from a provided zoom level.

How can I calculate this so that when I send out a download request it doesn't hit file not found?

Hope that makes sense.
Thank you.

PS: I don't have access to windows forms, I am using Unity3D engine, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be best off by going over the sourcecode of L.GridLayer which L.TileLayer is extended from. The `_pruneTiles` function would be a good starting point:

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/tile/GridLayer.js#L204

Answer (score 0):

You Can find a tutorial for embedding Leaflet in a C# app in this book:

[Leaflet.js Essentials - Chapter 6](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/leaflet-js-essentials/9781783554812/ch06.html)